# How to setup additional binding for the Federation Service in ADFS Server for Authentication

Tags: adfs, ws-federation, windows-server-2019

I have a single ADFS Server configured Non-Claims Aware relying party trust for my Application1, and now i have another application2 running in my LAN and i would like to add that application to the same ADFS server for Authentication.

1. Application1 --> https://app1login.domain.com/adfs/services/trust -- Working
2. Application2 --> https://app2login.domain.com/adfs/services/trust -- Http error 400

for point 2) i have setup `netsh http add sslcert hostnameport="app2login.domain.com:443" certhash="1255684215479212622" appid="{xxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxxx}" certstorename=MY` and now i am able to telnet to the app2login.domain.com and is working, but the URL https://app2login.domain.com/adfs/services/trust gives me http 400 error, where app1login.domain.com works fine.

Tried `Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding -Member hostname.domain.com -Thumbprint 'xxx2548526978456xxx'` but there is no Change, still http400

is there a possibility to make two different URL and sing-in page in a single ADFS Server for Two Different Application in the same domain

Comment: Are you trying to setup two Federation Service Name in a single ADFS Server Farm? and it looks like for App1 it should go to app1login and app2 it should go to app2login? isn't?

Comment: Yes that is Correct, this is what i am trying to accomplish. is that possible in the Single ADFS Server?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Years ago somehow I got ADFS to respond for adfs.mydomain.com and server1.adfs.mydomain.com. now I can't figure out how to do it...